# PyQt – Signal for object created in different thread doesn't work

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, signals-slots, qthread

I’m implementing multithreading in PyQt5 and Python 3.5 by running a `Worker` inside a `QThread`. In the following sample `thread2_worker` (runs inside a secondary thread and) creates `thread3_worker`, connects `thread3_worker.finished` signal to `thread3_worker_finished()` and runs it.

When `thread3_worker` is done it emits `finished` from within its thread but the connection doesn’t work. My guess is that it has to do with `thread3_worker` being created or connected not in the main thread but I'd welcome any clarification.

```
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QCoreApplication


class Worker(QObject):
    # Generic worker.
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, func):
        super().__init__()
        self.func = func

    def run(self):
        self.func()
        self.finished.emit()


def thread_factory(func):
    # Creates a Worker, a QThread and moves the Worker inside the QThread.
    worker = Worker(func)
    thread = QThread()
    worker.moveToThread(thread)
    thread.started.connect(worker.run)

    # Provision graceful termination.
    worker.finished.connect(thread.quit)
    worker.finished.connect(worker.deleteLater)
    thread.finished.connect(thread.deleteLater)

    return worker, thread


def wait():
    print("thread3:\t{}".format(QThread.currentThread()))
    time.sleep(3)


# finished signal of thread3_worker is never received.
@pyqtSlot()
def thread3_worker_finished():
    QCoreApplication.exit()


def create_thread3():
    print("thread2:\t{}".format(QThread.currentThread()))
    global thread3_worker, thread3
    # thread3_worker runs inside thread3, and all it does is call wait().
    thread3_worker, thread3 = thread_factory(wait)
    thread3_worker.finished.connect(thread3_worker_finished)  # FIXME Doesn't work.
    thread3.start()


app = QCoreApplication([])
print("Main thread:\t{}".format(QThread.currentThread()))
thread3_worker, thread3 = None, None
# thread2_worker runs inside thread2, and creates and runs thread3_worker.
thread2_worker, thread2 = thread_factory(create_thread3)
thread2.start()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-thread signals require an event-loop. Your `thread_factory` function connects the `finished` signal of the worker to the `quit` slot of its thread. The `quit` slot asks the thread to exit its event-loop.

So after thread3 starts, worker2 finishes and thread2 quits. Then when the `finished` signal of worker3 is emitted, there is no longer an event-loop running that can process it. If you comment out the line `worker.finished.connect(thread.quit)`, your example should work.

Comment: In fact, commenting out `worker.finished.connect(thread.quit)` fixed it. Thank you for sharing your expertise. I thought that each QThread had its own event loop.

Comment: @R01k. Each thread *does* have it's own event-loop. But worker3 needs the event-loop of thread2 (because the signal is emitted across threads).

Comment: Since the thread event loop keeps going after its worker has finished, does `thread.deleteLater()` still deletes the thread eventually?